# ld: library not found for -lX11

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, x11, compiler-flags

```
  1 CC = g++
  2 FLAGS = -g -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -I./glm -Wall
  3 LDFLAGS = -lX11 -lpthread
```

So I have these in my Makefile
but I get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lX11

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [compile-debug] Error 1
```

not sure what I should do to fix it

Comment: What is the output of `locate libX11` in your console?

Comment: Do apt install libx11-dev for Ubuntu, or yum install libX11-devel for Fedora/Red Hat. Or tell us what platform you are on.

Comment: It's on macOS Sierra

Comment: `locate libX11 /opt/X11/lib/libX11-xcb.1.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libX11-xcb.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.dylib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line in your makefile, because `libX11` is in a custom dir:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/X11/lib -lX11 -lpthread
```